# Getting highest value in many to many relation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I use Oracle DB .I have for example 3 tables:
User (id_user,username)
Interest (id_interest,name)
UserInterest(id_user_interest,id_user,id_interest)

I'd like to get all users, together with name of interest, which has the highest `id_user_interest` in `UserInterest` table. What is the best way to get it in sql query?

Thanks for the help

Comment: why don't you try it yourself first?

Comment: First retrieve the id max, then select the user associated to that id.

Comment: any ideas to do it without subquery?

Comment: I'd consider a GROUP BY.

Comment: select u.id_user, max(id_user_interest) from user u
LEFT join user_interest ui on u.id_user=ui.id_user
left join interest i on ui.id_interest=ui.id_interest 
group by u.id_user;    but how to get value from Interest table without subquery

Answer (score 0):

This should work to get the user with the highest user interest hopefully...
I do not have access to a compiler so this is all a guess.

```
SELECT TOP 1 U.username, I.name FROM user U
JOIN user_interest UI ON U.id_user=UI.id_user
JOIN interest I ON UI.id_interest=I.id_interest
GROUP BY U.username
ORDER BY UI.id_user_interest ASC
```

The `TOP` attribute grabs the first `x` amount of results and the `ORDER BY blank ASC` attribute orders the results from highest to lowest.

Hopefully this works for you, and GL programming. :)